# mysqldump --routines not including routines in created file

Tags: mysql

I want to create a FULL BACKUP of my database (MySQL) and I'm using the command:

```
mysqldump --routines -u dev_user -pblabla MyDB > d:\DB_Backups\%date%.sql
```

(this is on a Windows machine with a simple .bat script).

All of the sadden, I realized that all the routines stopped from being included in the created file.

Is there a way to create a **full backup** that can then be used to create a new DB (in production) with the whole contents of the database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Hello @MarkB. I just made a mall search or the word **Install** within the questions page and,,, found plenty of questions there, many with several answers. Perhaps I'm wrong, but this site appears to be suitable for questions like this one as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my windows mysql 5.6.24 install, I would use the `-R` switch, such as

```
mysqldump -u root -p -R so_gibberish > c:\nate\out123.sql
```

Note, the -p prompts for the password, and the db name is so_gibberish.

And the output file would contain the tables, procedures, and functions:

[image]

As an aside, please see the Mysql Manual Page on [Restrictions on Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html). Also, these fine answers on the stack:

1. [The role of the Definer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15714178) by ivanhoe
2. [Various topics plus updated comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63359) by Rolando

Though the above may not immediately address your issue, I am still looking, and may assist others.

Comment: Thank you @Drew for your suggestion, but it Did not work. Found the issue though. it turned out that there was a view that caused an error because it was pointing to a column whose name was changed. After correcting the name of the table column within the view definition, sqlit stated to work as mysqldump started to work as needed (yes, I agree with you, it should flag an error instead of not making a backup of the routines...). I'll mark your answer anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: I know there are several sources on the net that say to use the `-routines` switch. That is why I showed my version number `5.6.24` as `-routines` does not work but `--routines` with 2 slashes does. But please do share what command you used, your mysql version perhaps, that worked. Thx

Comment: Hello @Drew. The MySQL version is 5.7.9. Again, the issue was triggered by the fact that there was a VIEW pointing to a table column whose name was changed. I'm still puzzled by the fact that this error cause a **global** bypass of the routines dump, while the view is accessed from one single function.

Comment: I agree. I will circle back to it and thx for making that clear (which you did in your first comment) :p

Comment: You are most welcome @Drew. By the way, I'm about to post another question related to the same topic (mysqldump). You may have the answer to this one as well.

Comment: By the way, you might find a lot of cool info and a better home for your stuff over on [The dba Site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql) . It is fun to hang out over there and read Rolando's answers. His link is [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was missing the privilege `SELECT` on `mysql.proc` table for the user I was using with `mysqldump`.
According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines):

> Include stored routines (procedures and functions) for the dumped databases in the output. This option requires the SELECT privilege for the mysql.proc table.